# Is 'en-EU' a valid value for HTML 'lang' attribute?

Tags: html, markup, semantic-markup, lang

Markup for different editions of my news site...

- US Edition:

  ```
  <html lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US"> ... </html>
  ```
- India Edition:

  ```
  <html lang="en-IN" xml:lang="en-IN"> ... </html>
  ```
- Europe Edition (in this case not a specific country, i.e. news covers a broader region):

  ```
  <html lang="en-EU" xml:lang="en-EU"> ... </html>
  ```

I am depending on the markup of the page to make the target language/region of pages clear to the search engines because the different editions of the news site use a directory-based path (e.g. `example.com/eu/`) rather than a sub-domain (`eu.example.com`) or domain (e.g. `example.eu`) based path.

Now coming to the point, the `lang` attribute can have a value that is of the format *`language-region`*. But is `en-EU` a valid value?

**PS:** I think so, but I'd like to confirm with the knowledgeable folks here.

- Based on: http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry
- Via: http://www.w3.org/International/articles/language-tags/

Comment: "Because RFC 3066 didn't provide a list of valid subtags and just referred users to ISO 639, there was sometimes confusion about how to tag languages (...). Now all valid subtags are listed in a single [IANA registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry)". Ctrl + F in this registry does not show any entry for "en-EU"

Comment: No it is not: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533052(vs.85).aspx

Comment: @RobW Wrong. The language codes and region codes are listed separately. For instance, you can't find `en-US` either. Search for `European Union` and you'll see `Subtag: EU`.

Comment: The lang attribute does not indicate the target language/region of pages. It "... specifies the primary language for the element's contents and for any of the element's attributes that contain text" (HTML5). So it has nothing to do with the location of the target audience of your page.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Why not?

1. **HTML5** (CR) [defines](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/dom.html#the-lang-and-xml%3alang-attributes) that the "value must be a valid BCP 47 language tag, or the empty string".
2. [**BCP 47**](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/bcp/bcp47.txt) defines that the "IANA Language Subtag Registry […] contains a comprehensive list of all of the subtags valid in language tags".
3. [**IANA Language Subtag Registry**](http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry) contains the subtag `EU` of type `region`.

It’s not up to *anyone* to formally define if or which linguistic variations are spoken in which regions. Language changes constantly, speakers live and die everywhere.

Comment: Note that the subtag EU is the European Union, not whole Europe. For Europe, use subtag 150, e.g. `lang="en-150"`.