# Which element should I use for short group of foreign langague words?

Tags: css, html, semantic-markup

**I'm wondering which html element I should** use in a sentence or a paragraph (let say a `<p>` block) **for a borrowed word or one in a foreign language**, refering to a valid semantic. Here a few examples :

#### In English

> Tonight, I have a ***rendez-vous*** with a cute girl. (use of a French word)
>
> He was not speaking loudly, but not more silently, indeed ***mezzo voce*** (use of an Italian word)

#### In French

> Java n'est pas popriétaire, ***a contrario*** de .Net

In French, *at least*, this use of a foreign language require an italic formatting.

So I would like to combine both semantic and presentation. [Wikipedia article on Semantic HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML) give me a hint but I'm not convinced so far. Moreover, I might not have control over CSS, for instance in documentation (wiki), or in a description file (pom)
Which element suit my requierements the best  :

- `<i>` (surely not :) )
- `<em>` (maybe not :) )
- `<cite>`
- `<span lang="latin">`
- `<span class="borrowed">`
- combinaison of these ones
- an other tag

Comment: Do note that while this is about [tag:semantic-markup], it's not about [tag:semantic-web], about which the tag wiki says: "Representation of database record identifiers, columns and values as triples of URIs, thus enabling machines to share, merge and evaluate data from heterogeneous origins automatically". Be sure to check the tag descriptions; they're the best bet at getting the right eyes on your question.

Comment: Note that `latin` [would not be a valid value](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28112813/1591669) for the `lang` attribute.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[**W3C**](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/semantics.html#the-i-element) says

> The `i` element represents a span of text in an alternate voice or mood, or otherwise offset from the normal prose in a manner indicating a different quality of text, such as a taxonomic designation, a technical term, **an idiomatic phrase from another language**, transliteration, a thought, or a ship name in Western texts.

**My Emphasis**

Their example

```
 <p>There is a certain <i lang="fr">je ne sais quoi</i> in the air.</p>
```

Comment: Indeed, it may be the first time I see a correct use of italic tag !!! Would it pass html 5 / WAI compliance tests ?

Comment: It's not an italic tag any more, that's just the default formatting. It has been repurposed.

Comment: Thanks for you accurate and supported by strong references reply

Answer (score -1):

A **span** with one or multiple classes is usually the way to go.

```html
<span class="foreign-lang">bonjour</span>
```

with css:

```css
span.foreign-lang{
    font-style:italic;
}
```

Comment: "Usually" ? Is it a best pratice, do you gave any references (even the wikipedia link I provided). It seems obvious, but I don't see any general consensus or shared key-word. It may force syntaxic analyzer (or browser) to understand what foreign-lang refers to ?