# <html lang> Page in English targeting audiences of non-English speaking countries

Tags: html, internationalization, accessibility

Documentation on the `lang="language-TERRITORY"` attribute does not mention if it is valid to indicate that a webpage is written in one language, but targeting a territory which is not natively speaking that language.

E.g. if I were to write a webpage in English targeting a Swedish audience, is it valid to indicate this like so: `<html lang="en-SE">`?

https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-language-declarations#metadata says to indicate your target audience using the header field `Content-Language: sv-SE` (even if the page is written in English).
I realize I could do this and just put `<html lang="en">` but I'm still curious as to if the first approach would be valid or not.

Comment: I think your question is a duplicate to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28088512/1591669). Do you agree?

Comment: Agree! I did not find that one, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Section 3.2.5.2 of [the HTML5 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/dom.html#the-lang-and-xmllang-attributes) specifies (emphasis mine):

> The lang attribute (in no namespace) specifies **the primary language for the element’s contents** and for any of the element’s attributes that contain text. Its value must be a valid BCP 47 language tag, or the empty string. Setting the attribute to the empty string indicates that the primary language is unknown. [BCP47]

This seems to indicate that the `lang` attribute should describe the language of an elements contents and not the intended audience language.

Comment: That is correct, the document is written in English hence the `en` part of the `lang` attribute. But the region subtag `SE` in this case is used to (and I just found this): "indicate linguistic variations associated
   with or appropriate to a specific country, territory, or region." 
 - https://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47#section-2.2.4

Comment: I suppose this means that the first described approach trying to indicate "English document, Swedish audience" is not a valid one. But rather the territory/region subtag is used to describe dialects of that language. Hm.. solved I guess.