# Best practice usage of i18n language code to identify language and region?

Tags: internationalization, seo

I plan to use language/region codes in my current web project to identify language and region i.e. 'en-US' or 'de-CH'. 
Is a valid usage to use a code like i.e. 'en-IN' to identify content for India region with english text?

Comment: Why should it be an "invalid" use? [Wikipedia lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_localisation#Language_tags_and_codes) your in-question `en-in` as an example. As long as you're using common/valid iso codes to represent country and language there should be no problems at all, but even without that it totally depends on your project and who's utilising the language codes.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This is a good point. but maybe my example was not good, because english is official goverment language in india. What is about de-CN (german in China)? I think this will not appear in the iso list?!

Comment: I made an answer out of the findings that should clarify it. There is no official iso list for language-region combinations as far as I know

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is 'en-EU' a valid value for HTML 'lang' attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20722488/is-en-eu-a-valid-value-for-html-lang-attribute)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is about specifying the language in the actual HTML document. There might be different best practices for server-side coding that may depend on the actual programming technique used.

According to the way of how to declare a language in (X)HTML documents by the W3C [[1](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-language-declarations)] one should chose the language code based on the *Best Current Practice 47 "Tags for Identifying Languages" (RFC5646)*[[2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47)].

The suggest a format as follows

```
langtag   = language
           ["-" script]
           ["-" region]
           *("-" variant)
           *("-" extension)
           ["-" privateuse]
```

where among others the parts are defined as

```
language      = 2*3ALPHA            ; shortest ISO 639 code
region        = 2ALPHA              ; ISO 3166-1 code
```

Regarding the usage of the region part, the it says

> Region subtags are used to indicate linguistic variations associated
>      with or appropriate to a specific country, territory, or region.
>      Typically, a region subtag is used to indicate variations such as
>      regional dialects or usage, or region-specific spelling conventions.
>      It can also be used to indicate that content is expressed in a way
>      that is appropriate for use throughout a region, for instance,
>      Spanish content tailored to be useful throughout Latin America.
>
> The following rules apply to the region subtags:
>
> 1. Region subtags MUST follow any primary language, extended
>         language, or script subtags and MUST precede any other type of
>         subtag.
>
> [...]
>
> 6. There MUST be at most one region subtag in a language tag and the
>         region subtag MAY be omitted, as when it adds no distinguishing
>         value to the tag.

Nothing is said about a language to be an official language of the country nor actually a commonly spoken language. Only if distinguishing wouldn't add much value, you can omit the region but don't have to.

Note that the language tag is officially all *lowercase*, while the region codes are *uppercase*.

**tl;dr** As long as you're using valid iso codes to represent language and region you're conform with the best practice and standard when using e.g. `en-IN`

The list of language codes in ISO 639-2 may be found at https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/English_list.php while a list of region codes are [listed on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1) or you may use the search on the [official ISO website](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#search/code/).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I will test it in the web project and will give feedback if there are occurring problems.

Comment: Great. Please remember to accept and upvote if it helped ;)